# How do I interpret this matrix equation

Tags: summation, matrix-equations

$$Ax=b;\qquad b_k=\sum^n_{m=1}A_{k.m};\qquad A-\mathrm{HilbertMatrix}(funkcja\quad \mathbf{hilb}())$$

Also, $k = k + 1$ until it reaches $n$ value just like with $m$ value.

I've understood this equation as if $n = 3$, then we sum matrix $1\times1$ with matrix $2\times2$ and we sum it again with matrix $3\times3$.

I know that I can't sum matrix of different size.

Orignal image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with an example:
Suppose
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}A_{11}' & A_{12}' & \ldots & A_{1m}' \\
A_{21}' & A_{22}' & \ldots & A_{2m}' \\
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots \\
A_{n1}' & A_{m2}' & \ldots & A_{nm}'
\end{bmatrix}; x =\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_m\end{bmatrix} $$

Then we have:
$$Ax = \begin{bmatrix}A_{11}'x_1 + A_{12}'x_2 + \ldots + A_{1m}'x_m \\ A_{21}'x_1 + A_{22}'x_2 + \ldots + A_{2m}'x_m \\ \vdots \\ A_{n1}'x_1 + A_{n2}'x_2 + \ldots + A_{nm}'x_m\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m A_{1i}'x_i \\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m A_{2i}'x_i \\ \vdots \\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m A_{ni}'x_i\end{bmatrix}$$
If $Ax = b$, then we have:
$$b = \begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m A_{1i}'x_i \\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m A_{2i}'x_i \\ \vdots \\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m A_{ni}'x_i\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{bmatrix}$$
So for row $k$ we can say:
$$b_k = \sum_{i=1}^m A_{ki}'x_i$$
Defining $A_{ki} = A_{ki}' x_i$ gives us:
$$b_k = \sum_{i=1}^m A_{ki}$$
The difference between this and what you have must be that you're dealing with a square matrix $A$ in which case $m = n$. Then you get the desired result (upto changing indices)

Comment: I've one more question about it. So just adding A_1i in a row won't be enough yes ? I need to include also x_i ? I'm asking it because we did something similar. I had matrix 2x2 A = [ 1, 0.5 | 0.5 , 0.3] We added only rows so b = [ 1.5 | 0.8 ] b was a matrix 1x1. so x matrix was equal b/A = > b * A^-1. So x matrix which was 1x1 was equal [0.6509 | 0.3491 ] I don't know if it's correct because I don't have x given. I don't have anything so that's why I'm confused on how to solve it.

Comment: Hmmm maybe I misinterpreted your question. I thought you were trying to compute $b$ given that you already knew what $A$ and $x$ are. But if instead you're saying that $b$ is given based on the formula above (so that both A and b are known), and you want to compute $x$, then you would do $x= A^{-1} b$.

Comment: You were right b is unknown. x can be anything I guess. But the A is also unknown, All I have used is the function hilb(). It automatically made :  [ 1, 0.5 | 0.5 , 0.3]. So I thought that adding the rows will give me vector "b". But in your equation I also have to multiply it with "x" vector. As I've said before just adding stuff only from matrix A gave me matrix b and it somehow calculated the vector x. I did something like in your third equation for "bk" but I didn't include "x". And it somehow calculated ;D

I just got what is in the picture ;)

Comment: Or in other words I do have some A matrix that is random but I calculated b just by adding only the sum of A and I didn't include x, does this mean by default that x every x value x_1, x_2, x_3 .... x_4000 is equal 1 ? If I don't include x in the equation but I just add A for the b wektor. Let's say I have  A = [ 1, 0.5 | 0.5 , 0.3] I added them to calculate b = [ 1.5 | 0.8 ] and I didn't include x in the equation does this mean that the x is equal = [1, 1]  ? If yes then for any size of the matrix A if I add them like in the example I will always get x with only value "1" ?

Comment: @user331990 yes your $x$ vector will only have 1 as all of its entries